# How to colour a cell and keep the contents in maths-mode?

Tags: tables, color, siunitx, colortbl

I am trying to colour certain table cells in some `siunitx` S columns. The cell colour change with `xcolor`/`colortbl` works, but it seems to also change the cell contents to text-mode, which has unfortunate consequences when working with `siunitx` and negative numbers. The coloured cells  have a short text-mode minus sign while the rest stay in maths-mode with the longer minus sign. I'm not sure how to fix it. Here is an MWE and table image:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\blue}{\cellcolor{blue!25}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
  \begin{tabular}{
    S[table-format = 0.2]
    S[table-format = -0.2]}
    \toprule
    {A}  & {B}   \\ \midrule
    0.26 & -0.38 \\
    0.18 & \blue -0.34 \\
    \blue 0.31 & -0.36 \\ \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be `\newcommand*{\blue}{{\cellcolor{blue!25}}}` with an extra set of curly braces.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Thanks, that works perfectly! An edit with the reason it works would be great though :)